# connect multiple AD server through text file using powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have used the below code to connect with multiple servers which I have mentioned on to the text file. How can I connect ad servers and get the output in CSV format. if any changes required let me know

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\temp\Servers.txt"
ForEach($computername in $ServerList)
{
     Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -ComputerName $ComputerName |`
     Where{$_.PartialProductKey -and $_.Name -like "*Windows*"} | Select `
     @{Expression={$_.PSComputerName};Name="ComputerName"},`
     @{Expression={$_.PropertiesName};Name="Properties"} ,`
     @{Expression={$OperatingSystem[$($_.OperatingSystem)]};Name="OperatingSystem"}
}

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties name, OperatingSystem | Select name, OperatingSystem|Export-CSV -NoType c:\temp\JCcomputers.csv
```

Comment: You say it works but then ask how you can connect? What is the actual issue you're facing?

Comment: yes but iam not getting the output csv file and there is no error while running the script